# IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> не передается полный путь

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc

При публикации сайта в Microsoft Azure не передается полный путь файла только название. А когда локально из Visual Studio запускаешь все нормально в чем может быть проблема?

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create(TyreEntity tyreEntity, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> fileUpload) 
var UrlPhoto = fileupload.FileUpload("tyres", filename, file.FileName, file.ContentType);


@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "TyreEntities", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

<div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="fileUpload[0]" /><br />
        <input type="file" name="fileUpload[1]" /><br />
        <input type="file" name="fileUpload[2]" /><br />
        <input type="file" name="fileUpload[3]" /><br />
    </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Сохранить" id="SubmitMultiply" class="btn btn-default" accept="image/*"/>
            </div>
```

[image: Локально]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Браузеры не передают полный путь закачиваемого файла на удаленные сервера из соображений безопасности. Потому что из пути можно вытащить личную информацию (например, имя пользователя).

Обойти это нельзя - да и серверу должно быть все равно, по какому пути лежал файл у клиента. Данные файла надо читать не по пути (которого на сервере нет), а из InputStream.

Comment: Тогда почему может файл не сохранятся ?

Comment: @Anton он и не должен сохраняться. он вам приходит в виде стрима InputStream - а дальше что с ним хотите, то и делайте. Можете сохранить на диск (создав FileStream с нужным вам путем на сервере), можете закачать в storage (раз уж это Azure), можете в базу залить.

Answer (score 1):

Вместо

```
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(PathFile))
{
    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);                
}
```

Необходимо было

```
blockBlob.UploadFromStream(file.InputStream);
```

спасибо @PashaPash за подсказку